# Run Angular Service after 1st Service has completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have two Angular services. The first creates a cookie and the second sets a URL to include the created cookie. I need the first to run before the second. Normally this is not an issue when using a service as my services tend to use a http call that has a success output, but in this instance, I don't have a success call and I don't know how I can trigger that the first is complete. Here is my code as it stands:

```
// Set Session Cookie
appCheckCookie.getCookie();

// Get Cart URL with Session Cookie
$scope.cartURL = appCartURL.getCartURL();
```

I have tried wrapping these in their own functions and trying to execute them in order, but that didn't work. and I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
appCheckCookie.getCookie(function(){
$scope.cartURL = appCartURL.getCartURL();
});
```

Here are my two services:

```
appServices.factory('appCheckCookie', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var getCookie = function () {

        // Create session cookie
        function createCookie(name, value, days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        // Function to read cookie
        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        var x = readCookie('ppkcookie')

        if (x == null) {

            // Get Session ID from backend URL
            $http.post('/getSession', {}).success(function (data) {

                // Create cookie from session ID from backend. Note that setting the days to 0 deletes the cookie on browser close (recommended)
                createCookie('ppkcookie', data, 0);
                console.log("Cookie Created: " + data);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }

        else {
            var data = readCookie('ppkcookie');
            console.log("Cookie Exists: " + data);
        }
    };

        return {
            getCookie: getCookie
        };
}]),

appServices.factory('appCartURL', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var getCartURL = function () {

        // Function to read cookie
        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        var x = readCookie('ppkcookie')
        var baseCartURL = 'http://myecommsite.net/basket.html?Session_ID='
        var cartURL = baseCartURL + x;
        return cartURL;
    };

    return {
        getCartURL: getCartURL
    };
}]),
```

Comment: You should probably make your getCookie and getCartURL calls return promises, see the $q documentation on the angular site

Comment: Do you have an example of promise in a service?

Comment: What does your getCookie implementation look like, can you post more code?

Comment: Post updated. Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

In case of handling Async operations, `Promise` should be one of the APIs to consider.
[What is Promise?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
This may give you some inspirations of how to use it in your case:

```
// Namespace YourService
function readCookie(name) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
                resolve(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
        }

        resolve(null); // consider reject(null)?
    });
}

// Run in service

YourService.readCookie(name).then(function(cookieResponse) {
    // Run your second service after cookie retrieved
}).catch(function(reason) {
    // Catch reject
});
```

Another thing needs to be mentioned would be IE does not support `Promise` natively(Of course it doesn't..), so to use it in IE, you need to apply a [polyfill](https://www.promisejs.org/).

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Great advice on the use of $q. Along with a colleague, this is working since we only need the 1st service to signal that it is complete:

```
appServices.factory('appCheckCookie', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    var getCookie = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // Create session cookie
        function createCookie(name, value, days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        // Function to read cookie
        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        var x = readCookie('ppkcookie')

        if (x == null) {

           // Get GUID for the cookie               
           $http.post('/getSession', {}).success(function (data) {

                // Create cookie. Note that setting the days to 0 deletes the cookie on browser close (recommended)
                createCookie('ppkcookie', data, 0);
                console.log("Cookie Created: " + data);

                deferred.resolve(data);

            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }

        else { 
                var cookieExists = readCookie('ppkcookie');
                console.log("Cookie Exists: " + cookieExists);

                deferred.resolve(cookieExists);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };

        return {
            getCookie: getCookie
        };
}]),
```

Then in the controller:

```
appCheckCookie.getCookie().then(function (data) {

    // Get Cart URL
    $scope.cartURL = appCartURL.getCartURL();
    console.log($scope.cartURL);
});
```